# Battlestar Galactica Resurrection

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004, cylon

How do Cylons "upload" their consciousness to be downloaded into a new body upon death?

Some models are identical in every way to humans bar a reaction to a certain type of radiation (i.e. from Gaius Baltar's machine)

I would have assumed this requires a transmitter of some kind, which would probably be detectable as it would provide a difference between humans and the "skin-jobs".

Comment: Her spine does that glowy thing. Probably that where she keeps her gigantic antenna

Comment: wasnt there also a blood test to show who is cylon and who not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not fully answer your question, but the [process](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Resurrection_(RDM)) seems to be wireless and may rely on facilities whether planet-based or with ships like the Resurrection Hub and [data-stream](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Datastream).

> For resurrection to occur, the dying Cylon must be close to a
>   resurrection ship or hub, otherwise his or her consciousness risks
>   being permanently lost. **The transmission method of a Cylon's
>   consciousness has not been explained, but a form of wireless is
>   probable. Resurrection points identified include the Cylon homeworld,
>   the central Resurrection Hub, Resurrection Ships, and planet-based
>   facilities.** A rebirthing facility may have existed on occupied
>   Caprica. Within each resurrection point is at least one rebirthing
>   tank, where a duplicate body is immersed in a thick opaque substance
>   to await download (Downloaded).

In addition some of the pre-fall ers of the 12 Colonies' technology is featured in the prequel TV series *Caprica*. In that series viewers learn through the accomplishments of [Zoe](http://cylon.wikia.com/wiki/Zoe_Greystone) Greystone, Daniel Greystone, Lacey Rand, and Sister Clarance Willow that there is a link between a virtual reality with an ability to create a virtual avatar, whose information can also be downloaded into a robot body and can sustain said information transfer via MCP Chip.

But it should be noted that despite these accomplishments, that the final-five (No Exit, Final-Five Comic series, & comments from EPs about Caprica season 2) still made a deal with the Robot Cylons and possibly Zoe A, that resulted in the end of the first cylon war and the creation of the 8 new models, 7 of which are featured in Battlestar Galactica

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind Cylons use frequencies the Colonials can’t detect. As evidenced by them finding the tracking device in the middle of Galactica’s CIC, without knowing it was there for weeks.

Thus it stands to reason they are using one or more of these frequencies to transmit consciousness “files” to new bodies.

The Cylons are LightYears ahead of the Colonials technologically.